# 'moment is not a function' when referencing a self-made module in a React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, momentjs

I am trying to use a module I created in a simple React app using `react-boilerplate`. I am importing the module, but it is saying that `moment` within the module is undefined.

Here is the error and the logged moment just to show that `this.props.date` does indeed return a moment.

```
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, _d: 
index.js:23 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: moment is not a function
    at module.exports (index.js:23)
```

The module is on NPM and just does some simple logic based on a date using `moment`. Here is the `index.js` of that file.

## daysleft/index.js

index.js

```
const moment = require('moment');

moment.suppressDeprecationWarnings = true;
module.exports = (input, opts) => {
    if (input === undefined || input === '') {
        throw new TypeError('Expected a string, got nothing');
    }

    if (typeof input !== 'string') {
        if (typeof input !== 'object' && (input.isMoment === undefined || !input.isMoment())) {
            throw new TypeError(`Expected a string, got ${typeof input}`);
        }
    }

    opts = opts || {};

    if (opts.startDate && (typeof opts.startDate !== 'string')) {
        if (typeof opts.startDate !== 'object' && (opts.startDate.isMoment === undefined || !opts.startDate.isMoment())) {
            throw new TypeError(`Expected a string, got ${typeof opts.startDate}`);
        }
    }

    const startDate = moment(opts.startDate || moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    const endDate = moment(input);

    if (!endDate.isValid() || !startDate.isValid()) {
        throw new TypeError('Invalid date input');
    }

    return endDate.diff(startDate, 'days');
};
```

I then try to use it in a react app

### myApp/SomeComponent.js

```
render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper onClick={this.onClick}>
        <Label>{this.props.name}</Label>
        <DateView>{this.props.date.format('LL')}</DateView>
        <Hr />
        <DaysLeftContainer>
          <DaysLeft>
            {daysleft(moment(this.props.date))}
          </DaysLeft> days left
        </DaysLeftContainer>
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Link to the daysleft module incase it's needed: https://github.com/qbolt/daysleft/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you try to date conversion in component side?

Just pass the parameter as is then convert the value inside the your module function. Otherwise you need to import moment library in your component file.

Comment: you may try like this:
`moment(new Date(input))`